# I can't add my own index.php files in a custom directory, Wordpress keeps 'overriding' it

Tags: php, wordpress, path, http-status-code-404

So I have an `index.php` file, and I want to access it via `domain.com/custom/path/index.php` [i know the `index.php` doesn't need to be there since the browser grabs it automatically, but for the sake of the question I thought I'd just type it in],

but when I go to that path, wordpress kicks in and shows its default `No Results Found
The page you requested could not be found. Try refining your search, or use the navigation above to locate the post.`

Why is it doing that? And how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add a Rewrite rule to your .htaccess file, something along the lines of:

```
RewriteRule ^custom/path/.*$    -    [L]
```

The [L] tells the server to stop trying to rewrite a URL after it.